# Connect workgroup computers to a pc on a domain without password windows 7

Tags: networking, windows-7, vpn, domain, workgroup

I'm trying to setup a network for a client of mine. 
I need to make this network setup somewhat like this badly typed diagram:

```
                  Main Server
                     |
              domain through vpn
                     |
                   Server
                    / \
                  PC1 PC2
                         \
                          Printer
```

So basically, the secondary server connects through a vpn to the main server for files/db access and stuff like that. then PC1 and PC2 use files that live on the hdd of the secondary server. and of course, pc1 needs to access pc2's printer. I've got all that working, except, to connect to the secondary server's shared folder, i need to enter a username and password. That wont work for the software thats being used.

Is there any way to remove that password lock?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: +1 for the typed diagram :)

Comment: Whoops sorry, the secondary server is a windows 7 box. my boss doesn't want to work with win server cause it's a pain (and being a nix fan, i tend to agree)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable **anonymous** network access to your share.Thus this is **security flaw** and strongly **not recommended** (unless you have well known home network).

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755781%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_Local  :

To enable anonymous access on a local workstation or server computer

1. Open Local Security Settings. Click Start, click Control Panel,
   double-click Administrative Tools, and then double-click Local
   Security Policy.
2. In the console tree, double-click Local Policies, and then click
   Security Options.
3. In the details pane, right-click Network access: Let Everyone
   permissions apply to anonymous users, and then click Properties.
4. On the Local Security Settings tab, click Enabled, and then click
   OK.

Next step is to grant access for "**Everyone**" on share level and filesystem level.

After that you will be able to access folder anonymously, thus without any authentication.

This is just alternative, in your situation I would recommend  **billc.cn**'s answer.

Comment: thanks, this worked the way i needed it and as its only a wired system, the security flaw is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to enter any password if there's a user with the same username/password combination on the server as the current user. Windows automatically tries to use the current user's credentials to log on to the remote server. This is the most secure and painless way to do it.

Alternatively you can setup a domain and make all computers join it.

Another alternative is to use the remember my password feature. You can also force the password to me remembered via command line:

```
net use \\server_name * /user:user_on_server /remember
```

and then type the password when prompted.